# Opencart3: How is implemented email notifications

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

In Opencart 1.5.X email notifications for new order\customers\etc was implemented via catalog/model/checkout/order.php in confirm() method. 
But in OC3.X this code was completely rewrited and I can not find how this functionality is implemented in this version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list of notifications implements in different places. Email notifications mostly implements in **/catalog/controller/mail/**

There you can find **affiliate**, **forgotten**, **order**, **register** and **transaction**.

Each controller related to one or more different models. You can find a related models using search in these controller, looking for `$this->model_`.

For example **/catalog/controller/mail/order.php** contains references mostly on **/catalog/model/checkout/order.php** (`$this->model_checkout_order`).

Comment: Ok. As I understand, when order is on checkout stage, appropriate payment method (e.g. cod) invokes appropriate class in /catalog/controller/mail folder?
I need to know where in OC3 invokes /catalog/controller/mail/order.php/add() when customer adds new order.

Comment: I have found. In this version OC uses Events system, so before $this->model_checkout_order->addOrderHistory, invokes:

Trigger

catalog/model/checkout/order/addOrderHistory/before

Action

mail/order